# Select data for couple of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a simple Chat App. Imagine that when `Michael` click on `John`  I have to show messages which the messages sent to `John` and receive from `John`.

I will continue to the problem, first look DB structure, please.

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Email NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LastEntryTime DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
IP NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE MessageContent(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
MessageContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
Size BIGINT NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Messages(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Id_Sender INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id),
Id_Receiver INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id),
Id_MessageContent INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MessageContent(Id),
SentAt DATETIME NOT NULL,

CHECK(Id_Sender != Id_Receiver)
)
```

In this query, I take all message which sends by `John`. But I want to take messages which send to `John` from `Michael` and receive from `John` to `Michael`.

```
SELECT MessageContent,Users.Id FROM MessageContent,Messages,Users
where users.Id = Messages.Id_Sender and MessageContent.Id = Messages.Id_MessageContent
and users.Email='mailofJhon.com'
```

With this query, I did not take the correct result. I know it is an unfinished query.
But do not know how I have to continue this query.

What can i do?

Comment: Send some data and also the result that you expect, please.

Comment: First I suggest you google ANSI joins.  Next, to solve your issue read about ```UNION```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join twice the table `Users` (to get he sender and the receiver) to the other 2 tables:

```
SELECT c.MessageContent 
FROM MessageContent c 
INNER JOIN Messages m ON c.Id = m.Id_MessageContent
INNER JOIN Users us ON us.Id = m.Id_Sender
INNER JOIN Users ur ON ur.Id = m.Id_Receiver 
WHERE 
  us.Email IN ('mailofJohn.com', 'mailofMichael.com') 
  AND 
  ur.Email IN ('mailofJohn.com', 'mailofMichael.com')
```

If there is a case that a user can send a message to themselves then you must add another condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
AND us.Email <> ur.Email
```

Comment: Say what now..?